# Running python shell on spark (1.5) on ubuntu

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to run python spark shell but after running the following command from my console I am getting following error. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this. I was able to run Scala shell but since I am more comfortable with python I wish to run python shell. Thanks in Advance.

```
hduser@Hadoop1:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/pyspark --master yarn-client
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
15/11/07 16:47:36 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.1
15/11/07 16:47:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/11/07 16:47:37 WARN SparkConf: 
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS was detected (set to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with conf/spark-defaults.conf to set defaults for an application
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-java-options to set -X options for a driver
 - spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to set -X options for executors
 - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS to set java options for standalone daemons (master or worker)

15/11/07 16:47:37 WARN SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411' as a work-around.
15/11/07 16:47:37 WARN SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.driver.port=53411' as a work-around.
15/11/07 16:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hduser); users with modify permissions: Set(hduser)
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.10.2:53411]
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53411.
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/11/07 16:47:38 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-e9bab824-356d-408a-9a73-164af442e378
15/11/07 16:47:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.0 MB
15/11/07 16:47:39 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-63be26c5-e11a-455e-8b29-e33425a75300/httpd-348efa50-efa1-4ec2-8fc3-794556cf2afe
15/11/07 16:47:39 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/11/07 16:47:39 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 36265.
15/11/07 16:47:39 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/11/07 16:47:44 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/11/07 16:47:44 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.10.2:4040
15/11/07 16:47:44 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/11/07 16:47:44 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at Hadoop1/192.168.10.2:8050
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 8 NodeManagers
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (12288 MB per container)
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
15/11/07 16:47:45 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15/11/07 16:47:46 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://Hadoop1:9000/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1446315521245_0017/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar
15/11/07 16:47:47 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://Hadoop1:9000/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1446315521245_0017/pyspark.zip
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip -> hdfs://Hadoop1:9000/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1446315521245_0017/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-63be26c5-e11a-455e-8b29-e33425a75300/__spark_conf__6924722000222394217.zip -> hdfs://Hadoop1:9000/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1446315521245_0017/__spark_conf__6924722000222394217.zip
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hduser); users with modify permissions: Set(hduser)
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO Client: Submitting application 17 to ResourceManager
15/11/07 16:47:48 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1446315521245_0017
15/11/07 16:47:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:49 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1446932868722
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://Hadoop1:8088/proxy/application_1446315521245_0017/
     user: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:51 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.10.7:48229/user/YarnAM#-1213485989])
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> Hadoop1, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://Hadoop1:8088/proxy/application_1446315521245_0017), /proxy/application_1446315521245_0017
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1446315521245_0017 (state: RUNNING)
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.10.7
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1446932868722
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://Hadoop1:8088/proxy/application_1446315521245_0017/
     user: hduser
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1446315521245_0017 has started running.
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54290.
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54290
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.10.2:54290 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.10.2, 54290)
15/11/07 16:47:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/11/07 16:47:56 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.10.7:48229
15/11/07 16:47:56 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.10.7:48229] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
15/11/07 16:47:56 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.10.7:48229
15/11/07 16:48:01 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.10.7:34460/user/YarnAM#-1591425531])
15/11/07 16:48:01 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> Hadoop1, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://Hadoop1:8088/proxy/application_1446315521245_0017), /proxy/application_1446315521245_0017
15/11/07 16:48:01 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
15/11/07 16:48:02 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.10.7:34460
15/11/07 16:48:02 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@192.168.10.7:34460] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
15/11/07 16:48:02 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 192.168.10.7:34460
15/11/07 16:48:02 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.10.2:4040
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
15/11/07 16:48:02 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/11/07 16:48:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
15/11/07 16:48:14 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
15/11/07 16:48:14 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(pyFiles=add_files)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 113, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 174, in _do_init
    self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 259, in _start_update_server
    server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
>>>
```

Comment: What happen when you `ping Hadoop1`?

Comment: hduser@Hadoop1:/usr/local/spark$ ping Hadoop1
It is working fine

Comment: I just want to add that, Hadoop1 is my master node and I have 8 slave nodes.

Comment: It should be a network setup issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4475

Comment: I think if it would have been network setup issue then I shouldn't be able to run scala-shell too, but I can run scala-shell so I think there is some other issue, but not sure. Thank you for your help. Will update once I am able to solve.